# How can I split a data frame containing rows of one string in each into multiple columns?

Tags: r, dataframe, split

For example if I had multiple rows containing a sentence such as "I love dogs" and I wanted to keep the same number of rows in the data frame but have three columns where it would be 
"I" "love" "dogs" in the respective columns etc. How can I split the one original column at the spaces in the string?

Answer (score 0):

We can use `strsplit` and `do.call`.

```
data <- "I love dogs"
do.call(rbind,strsplit(data," "))
#     [,1] [,2]   [,3]  
#[1,] "I"  "love" "dogs"
```

Or for many strings.

```
data <- data.frame(love = c("I love dogs","I love cats","I love bears","I love dolphins","I love otters"),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
do.call(rbind,strsplit(data$love," "))
#     [,1] [,2]   [,3]      
#[1,] "I"  "love" "dogs"    
#[2,] "I"  "love" "cats"    
#[3,] "I"  "love" "bears"   
#[4,] "I"  "love" "dolphins"
#[5,] "I"  "love" "otters"
```

Comment: can I do this for an entire data frame containing multiple rows with a string in each?

Comment: Yes. See my edited answer.